# Como usar rack-cors en rails 6.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

Estoy intentando enviar unos archivos al bucket S3 pero cada vez que le doy enviar en la consola me aparece este error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://the-bucket' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

lo intente instalando la gema rack-cors y creando un archivo en los initialiazers

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put]
    end
  end
```

pero aun asi no he podido solventar el problema.

Estoy trabajando con la version 6.1.1 de rails

Comment: ¿que información envías en el header del request? los response headers también son importantes, ¿no será problema de [tu configuración en S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html)?

Comment: Si correcto Alter, se solventó desde aws